# Particular line match using regex

Tags: regex

```
This script may take a while to run, especially on a busy podmaster.
Generating Syslog TopN list on node for last 3 hours.

        Top 5 hosts for Day: Oct8 between 02:00:00 and 02:59:59
            Rank       Number of Alerts Host
            ----       ---------------- ----
        1       3124        aaa
        2       2294        bbb
        3       2157        ccc
        4       832     ddd
        5       816     eee

Top 5 hosts for Day: Oct8 between 01:00:00 and 01:59:59
        Rank       Number of Alerts Host
        ----       ---------------- ----
        1       5495        fff
        2       2625        ggg
        3       998     hhh
        4       752     iii
        5       741     jjj

Top 5 hosts for Day: Oct8 between 00:00:00 and 00:59:59
        Rank       Number of Alerts Host
        ----       ---------------- ----
        1       2747        kkk
        2       876     lll
        3       780     mmm
        4       724     nnn
        5       309     ooo
```

I have used the below regular expression to match this format.

```
\s+[1]+\s+([\d]+).*
```

the output for above expression is

```
$1 = 3124 5495 2747
```

But I need the regular expression to match the ranks rank 1 separately.

```
Example output:
$1 = 3124 
$2 = 5495 
$3 = 2747
```

Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: Could you show us the script you're using? Where does the input come from?

Comment: I'm not using the script. I have tried the same in
http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to the below if the input contains the exact string you posted.

```
(?s)\s+1+\s+([\d]+).*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+).*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tD6vY9/3)

For javascript,

```
\s+1+\s+([\d]+)[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)[\S\s]*?\s+1+\s+([\d]+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eE7lT6/1)

Comment: Is there any possibility to match the same with three regex.
e-g 1. regex matches - 3124
2. regex matches - 5495
3. regex matches - 2747

Comment: I want three separate regex to match the particular line.

Comment: three separate regex to match three separate lines?

Comment: It is working good. But if we get three regex to check three separate lines is more useful for me.

Comment: Thanks Avinash. It is working fine. Is there any possibility to match only second line using regex?
e-g. output::  $2 = 5495

Comment: Are you running javascript?

Comment: Yes. I using JavaScript engine.

Comment: @Vasanth added solution for js

Comment: Still I'm not getting expected result.
I want three separate regex to match three separate lines using JavaScript regex engine.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your regex.

That's just a formatting difference:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = do {local $/; <DATA>};

my @ones = $data =~ m/^\s*[1]\s+([\d]+)/mg;

for my $i (0..$#ones) {
    printf "\$%d = %s\n", $i+1, $ones[$i];
}

__DATA__
        Rank       Number of Alerts Host
        ----       ---------------- ----
        1       3124        abc
        2       2294        bcd



        Rank       Number of Alerts Host
        ----       ---------------- ----
        1       5495        cdf
        2       2625        klm


        Rank       Number of Alerts Host
        ----       ---------------- ----
        1       2747        lll
        2       876         jjj
```

Outputs:

```
$1 = 3124
$2 = 5495
$3 = 2747
```

<kbd>[**live demo**](http://ideone.com/Uf0xtm)</kbd>

Comment: @M42 You may be right.  Obviously, it would be helpful if he supplied more information such as the language and code he's currently using.  I think this is the best advice I can give considering the lack of info.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rank.*?\n.*?\n1\s*(\d+)
```

Try this.Set flag `g`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/58

Answer (score 0):

Noticed this in your duplicate question about [IPautomata designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253105/line-match-using-regex-in-javascript-engine)

> We are using new IPsoft tool which has two options.
>
> ```
> 1. Line Filter(JavaScript regex)
> 2. Match(JavaScript regex)
> ```
>
> For example if we need to match the alertcount(3124). First filter the line >than match the same. Like that I need to match another two alert count(5495 >and 2747). Please help me to sort it out.

If you are trying to capture the output from a host command state, or any state's OUTPUT variable, you can use the Extract Variable tab:

`Name: capture_variable
Line Filter: \s+1\s+.*
Match: .*1\s+(\d+).*
Replace: $1`

this will set the capture_variable equal to a multi-line string like this:

```
3124
5495
2747
```