# Line match using Regex in JavaScript engine

Tags: javascript, regex

**Input:**

```
This script may take a while to run, especially on a busy podmaster.
    Generating Syslog TopN list on node for last 3 hours.

            Top 5 hosts for Day: Oct8 between 02:00:00 and 02:59:59
                Rank       Number of Alerts Host
                ----       ---------------- ----
            1       3124        aaa
            2       2294        bbb
            3       2157        ccc
            4       832     ddd
            5       816     eee

    Top 5 hosts for Day: Oct8 between 01:00:00 and 01:59:59
            Rank       Number of Alerts Host
            ----       ---------------- ----
            1       5495        fff
            2       2625        ggg
            3       998     hhh
            4       752     iii
            5       741     jjj

Top 5 hosts for Day: Oct8 between 00:00:00 and 00:59:59
        Rank       Number of Alerts Host
        ----       ---------------- ----
        1       2747        kkk
        2       876     lll
        3       780     mmm
        4       724     nnn
        5       309     ooo
```

I have used the below regular expression(JavaScript engine) to match this format.

```
\s+[1]+\s+([\d]+).*
```

the output for above expression is

```
312454952747
```

We are using new IPsoft tool which has two options.

1. Line Filter(JavaScript regex)
2. Match(JavaScript regex)

For example if we need to match the alertcount(3124). First filter the line than match the same. Like that I need to match another two alert count(5495 and 2747).
Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: specify the needs in this question about that you want three separate patterns for getting the above numbers.

Comment: If we use Perl also no problem.